# Undergrad Textbook on the Dirac Picture

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations

From what I've seen, undergraduate textbooks on quantum mechanics generally focus on the Schrodinger picture and only possibly mention the Heisenberg and Dirac pictures near the end of the texts.  Is there an undergraduate textbook that focuses on the [Dirac picture](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_picture) instead?